# Listing Currently Installed Steam Games in C#

Tags: c#, steam

Looking for a quick way of listing all currently installed steam games in c#. I've been using a method of checking the registry at the moment for installed apps, but if the user has their steam games on another hard drive and has swapped it into the machine then they won't be in the registry right?

So Looking for a way. Has anyone got any experience with the SteamAPI to point me in the right way if there is anything in there at all? Or any experience with this sort of thing?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Connect the steam API and take the information which you need.

Comment: http://steamcommunity.com/id/timvisee/games?tab=all&xml=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know the SteamApps directory, you can look at each appmanifest_1010.acf files in that directory. The numbers are the game's appid, and the file contains information about that game including its name and install path.